# How to give each local user an unique ID? C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a personal project to kill some time when I'm bored. So I have this login + register application which saves all data locally. Each generated user gets it's own map with his login credentials located in a text file.

However I'm having troubles giving each map an unique ID, this is my code for so far and I can't manage to make it work.

```
            const int User_ID = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < i; i++)
            {

            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\" + User_ID);

            var sw = new StreamWriter("data\\" + User_ID + "\\data.txt");

            sw.WriteLine(User_ID);
            sw.Close();
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: If you're using a database, as the tags suggest, most have some mechanism to generate an identifier when inserting a record.

Comment: can you modify the tag from database to flat file system, to denote that you don't need a Database based solution

Comment: I do not have a real database, each user gets his own map + textfile with his credentials located. Sorry.

Comment: what is the purpose of the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually you would use instead of an int a GUID for the user id:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 1):

Generating a GloballyUniqueIdentifier (GUID) will be the best approach because you need not think about the earlier UserIds generated so far by your application. Because GUIDs are guaranateed to be created without collision

```
string User_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < i; i++)
{
}

Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\" + User_ID);
var sw = new StreamWriter("data\\" + User_ID + "\\data.txt");

sw.WriteLine(User_ID);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: You beat me at submitting the answer first, Just thought there should be some background justification on why GUID works out well, in case OP is not aware about GUIDs :)

Comment: @TestT I have converted GUID to a string value so that it doesn't create any issue with the path creation. If you see any error, can you share the information. That would help community members to understand & give answers faster